# How to suppress MongoSocketOpenException in the logs - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a micro batch that runs every 5 mins, it works fine, but everytime it runs it'll throw that error in the logs at the beginning and then continue without any issues:

```
org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:81)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62)
```

Connection String in the properties file: `mongoDBConnectionString=mongodb://svc.myserviceid:xxxxxxxxxx@server1.mycompany.com:30200,server2.mycompany.com:30200,/?authMechanism=PLAIN&replicaSet=myreplicateset&readPreference=primaryPreferred&authSource=$external&ssl=true mongoDBName=mydatabase`

Spring boot version: `1.5.3.RELEASE`

Mongo version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my main Spring boot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTask
public class xxApplication { ... }
```

I tried excluding (exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class}) with or without @EnableAutoConfiguration and it didn't work.

I tried adding indiviual spring properties in the properties file, and it didn't work either.

Let me know if there is anything I can do to prevent this from showing in the logs.

Comment: I think this is expected exception. When your applications starts, your old socket for some reason is unhealthy, so it fails, then driver just recreate it and normal workflow happens.

Comment: True, I was just looking for a way to hide that exception in the logs.